# UpdateSourceTrigger dropdown is disabled

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to set UpdateSourceTrigger in designer and whenever I try to do the same, drop down box is disabled and because of that I can not select anything.

In my simplest example, I am trying set one textbox's value to another textbox's value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "Binding Direction" to TwoWay. That's the default for TextBox.Text, but that dialog wants you to say "TwoWay" explicitly.